# Keeping multiple projects in sync using Git

Tags: git, multiple-repositories

Let's say I have two projects that I manage with Git (in different repos). I work on project1 completely independently from project2. I realize now that I can use project2 as a third-party software in project1. I want to keep these projects independent and not use submodules, but I want to always have the latest version of both projects. So when I'm working on project1 and I do a `git pull`, I want to pull in all the changes from project1 *and* project2. How would I do this?

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Comment: Can you give a little background on why you want to avoid submodules?  There are four options that spring to mind: 1.) submodules, which you don't want 2.) put everything in one repository, but you want them independent 3.) use a symlink from projec1 to project2, but `pull` won't behave like you want and it's fragile 4.) write some scripts that keep your projects in sync the way you want, but it's more complex and `pull` still won't work how you like.  Hopefully there's another option that I'm not thinking of...

Answer (score 0):

Submodules were made for this. If you don't track what version of project 2 you were using for each commit of project 1, you have thrown out the window many benefits of source control itself. Try and use `git blame` with your approach, for example.

You can update your submodule with `git submodule foreach git pull`. Pressing `ctrl-R` and typing `submodule` will find you that whole line next time - even without typing the whole word.